# SuccessFactors LMS: Why is a "course session ended" page displayed after I close my scorm 2004 package?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, lms, sap-successfactors

I get the attached "current course session has ended" page in SAP SuccessFactors LMS after I close a scorm package. Why does this happen?[image]

Some further info to describe the implemented package:

- scorm package is 2004 4th edition.
- LMS is SAP SuccessFactors (xxx-plateau.com)
- cmi.interactions are used to track whether user have completed parts of the sco content.
- cmi.lesson_location is used to bookmark the last content visited within the sco which it will return to on opening the sco again.
- package is set to cmi.exit = suspend and calls cmi.commit on close.

According to the admin of the SuccessFactors installation, the "content session ended" page displaying is an "error". Its clearly a SuccessFactors page, its not an error but rather user feedback. I'd like to find out why it displays & how to prevent it displaying if you know.

Comment: you could launch a javascript debug session in your browser (F12) and look for any errors in your courses scorm 2004 runtime?

Comment: @Whyan I have run a debug & there is no debug. This page appears after the package has been closed & on next launch of the course. Have you seen the "content session has ended" page before?

Comment: At the very least you should be able to discover (using browser F12 debug) whether the call to LMSCommit and/or Terminate returns true or false. I have never seen the "content session has ended" page before.

Comment: Thanks Whyan. I agree on looking at logs for what should be called & have. The mystery is the "content session has ended" page - no one I have spoken to has seen this before and its not part of the package. It's not in the Success Factors documentation either.